# Datagrid selects the wrong custom cell in my datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, selection, itemrenderer

I am working on a problem since a week soon, but I still couldn't make it work as expected. I have a DataGrid which has HBox with a CheckBox an a Label as itemRenderer (see Code below). When I tap in to the Cell the standard itemEditor pops up and lets you enter the content of the label. Thats the standard behavior. I works fine except for 2 problems:

1. If I enter to much text, the horizontal srollbar pops up, and the cell is filled with that scrollbar. As you see I tried to set the horizontalScrollPolicy to off, but that doesnt work at all... I tried to do that for all the different elements, but the failure is still existent.
2. When I have filled more than one row, there is an other mistake happening. If I tap on a row, the datagrid selects the one below that row. That's only if one line is already selected. If I tap outside the datagrid and then, tap at any row the itemEditor of the right row will show up... Is there anything now wright in the setup of my set data method?

__

```
package components
{
 import mx.containers.HBox;
 import mx.controls.CheckBox;
 import mx.controls.Label;

 public class ChoiceRenderer extends HBox
 {

  private var correctAnswer:CheckBox;
  private var choiceLabel:Label;

  public function ChoiceRenderer()
  {
   super();
   paint();
  }

  private function paint():void{
   percentHeight = 100;
   percentWidth = 100;
   setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", "off");
   super.setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", "off");

   correctAnswer = new CheckBox;
   correctAnswer.setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", "off");  
   addChild(correctAnswer);

   choiceLabel = new Label;
   choiceLabel.setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", "off");   
   addChild(choiceLabel);  


  }

     override public function set data(xmldata:Object):void{
      if(xmldata.name() == "BackSide"){
       var xmlText:Object = xmldata.TextElements.TextElement.(@position == position)[0];
       super.data = xmlText;
       choiceLabel.text = xmlText.toString();
       correctAnswer.selected = xmlText.@correct_answer;

      }               
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Markus

Answer (score 0):

- I am not sure if this is the reason behind your issues, but the standard way of creating children is to override the `createChildren` method.
- Also, you are missing an `else` statement - you are not calling `super.data` when `if` condition fails. That doesn't look good either.

Try:

```
package components
{
 public class ChoiceRenderer extends HBox  {
  private var correctAnswer:CheckBox;
  private var choiceLabel:Label;

  public function ChoiceRenderer() {
    super();
    percentHeight = 100;
    percentWidth = 100;
    setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", "off");
  }
  override protected function createChildren():void {
    super.createChildren();
    correctAnswer = new CheckBox();
    addChild(correctAnswer);
    choiceLabel = new Label();
    choiceLabel.setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", "off");   
    addChild(choiceLabel);  
  }
  override public function set data(xmldata:Object):void {
    if(xmldata.name() == "BackSide") {
       var xmlText:Object = xmldata.TextElements.TextElement.(@position == position)[0];
       super.data = xmlText;
       choiceLabel.text = xmlText.toString();
       correctAnswer.selected = xmlText.@correct_answer;
    }
    else {
      //what if xmldata.name() is not "BackSide"?
      //you are not calling super.data in that case
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately It doesn't solve the two problems. The reason why I don't have a else statement, is because sometimes the function calls the whole row (BackSide in the xml) and sometimes it calls cell's with a TextElement... I dont know why, but exactly...

Comment: @Markus As for scroll bar issue, try commenting out percent width and percent height lines.

Comment: doesn't change anything... but I added the setStyle("horizontalAlign", "center"); statement, and that had an effect!... I don't get that...

Answer (score 0):

- in order to avoid scroll bar you have to let datagrid have variable height

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dg"
 dataProvider="{dp}"
 variableRowHeight="true" 
 creationComplete="dg.height=dg.measureHeightOfItems(0,dp.length)+dg.headerHeight+2"/>
```

Comment: Hi Nishu, Thanks for this answer, but it is not the vertical scrollbar which is my problem, it is the horizontal...

Comment: apologies for misread. 

have you tried setting wordwrap to true and datagridcolum.width to max of updated cell and datagridcolumn.width