# flex custom itemRenderer doesn't use the styles specified

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

I have a custom item renderer which I use for my DataGrid. The DataGrid has specified selectionColor, rollOverColor and themeColor. The Problem is that the custom item renderer, does ignore those colors, and doesn't give any Feedback...

I tried to add the lines:

```
setStyle("selectionColor", 0xEDF1F7);
setStyle("rollOverColor", 0xE1F5DE);
setStyle("themeColor", 0x3569B0);
```

But with no effect...

Who can help on that?

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 2):

Those styles won't apply to the component you are using for your itemRenderer (which you don't mention). They're styles of the DataGrid itself.

So let's say you're using a Canvas. Try setting the backgroundAlpha of the Canvas to 0.0 so that your DataGrid's selection and other colors will show through.

Comment: Hi Robusto, thanks for your hint, I'm using a HBox and added this.setStyle("backgroundAlpha", 0.0); but that didn't help...

Comment: Try setStyle("backgroundAlpha","0.0").

Comment: Are you using an image graphic as an itemRender?

Comment: No, my item renderer is a HBox consisting a checkbox and a label... you can see the code in the following threat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449163/follow-up-question-problem-with-selecting-a-custom-itemrenderer-in-a-datagrid

Comment: You had 1999 points! I think your efforts today are worth it! ;-) Thanks!